# a bug related to While and For loops in javascript...!

Tags: javascript, debugging, loops

I have some trouble as simple as debugging a for loop or a while loop.
Do you have any clue? a function that returns data without any iteration works fine but not the loop.

```
<script language = "javascript">
        function h(arr)
    {
    <![CDATA[

        var ref = arr[0];

        i = 0
        while(i<arr.length){
            if(arr[i]!= arr[0])
            {
                return 1
            }
            i++;
        }
        return 0

    ]]>
    }
```

I need it for the XSL not to confuse the < with the tag but consider it as a comparison operator.
HELP

Comment: And what data are you passing into this function h? Example call would be nice.

Comment: What is your question? And why are there CDATA tags in your function?

Comment: Also what is with the weird placement of CData tags?

Answer (score 1):

Try correcting the following:

The CData tags will want to go outside the function (immediately below and above the open and close script tags respectively). These are only really needed if you are validating your HTML:
http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
     // content of your Javascript goes here
]]>
</script>
```

Add semi-colons on `i=0` and `return 0` lines.

Use `!==` instead of `!=` this will do a type comparison as well.

Give us some more info. Its hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

what is <![CDATA[ doing inside your code?

Comment: I need it for the XSL not to confuse the < with the tag but consider it as a comparison operator.